# Sample applications based on First Order Logic

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic, applied-theory

I often hear about benefits of FOL, but I wonder what are some of its real world applications?

1. Could someone please provide samples/case studies of applications of FOL that address real world challenges?
2. What are typical tools / programming languages used in developing such applications?

Note: If this is not the correct forum for this question, please let me know which forum is the best. Many thanks in advance.